# MacBook not asking for password after sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bug, login-screen

My mid-2015 MacBook Pro (Sierra 10.12.2) skips the login screen when waking from sleep, it goes straight to my desktop.

I have my System Preferences set to require my password 1 minute after being put to sleep but it doesn't seem to be working.

Anyone have an idea of what the problem might be?

Comment: I have seen the same problem on my mid-2014 15" mbp after update to sierra 10.12.2.

Comment: I have the same issue. MacBook Pro Late 2013. Up to date BigSur. Waking up after sleep doesn't ask for a password but in a random manner. Sometimes it asks, sometimes it doesn't. It's certainly not a trustworthy mechanism when it comes to security... On the other hand, it asks 100% of the time after locking the screen.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if you set it in the correct place, but the setting should be at:

> 1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click General.
> 2. Select “Require password… after sleep or screen saver begins.”
> 3. Click the pop-up menu and choose the time that passes before a password is required.

Source: [OS X Yosemite: Require a password after waking your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18669)

[image: System Preferences screenshot]

Comment: OP already said they have "set to require my password 1 minute after being put to sleep but it doesn't seem to be working".

Comment: Instead of 1 minute, try out "immediately after sleep". Does it work?

Comment: That seems to work if I put the mac to sleep and try to start it up again immediately after but if I leave it sleeping for any extended period of time and come back to it, it'll open to my desktop again and skip the login page.

Comment: I thought it may have been bluetooth related so I also unchecked the "Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer" option in the System Preferences but not luck there either!

Comment: Is it modifiable from command line?

Comment: Where is this option in Sonoma?

Answer (score 3):

I found that I was able to fix this problem on 10.12.6 using the following steps:

1. Set "Require password" to "immediately".
2. Lock the screen or put the machine to sleep.
3. Set "Require password" back to your preferred time delay (1 minute).

Answer (score 1):

Steps I did to make laptop lock as intended.

1. Require Password > Immediately
2. Apply and close that setting window, quit "Settings"
3. Unplug USB device *before* initiating Lock
4. In my case it was a USB Headset that was preventing Lock
5. Enjoy computer being locked.

Comment: Thank you! In my case it was not the usb but regular earphone in audio jack. I removed earphone, locked the machine and it was asking password. Now even there is one attached it works as expected.

Comment: Where is the require password immediately option?

Answer (score 1):

**OS X High Sierra**

> 1.  menu > System Prefrences > **Users & Groups**
> 2. Click **Login options** at the bottom of the sidebar
> 3. Settings might be disabled. Unlock them (by clicking the lock at the bottom) to make changes.
> 4. After unlocking, set **Automatic login** to "Off"

[image: Settings]
[image: Login Options]
[image: Enable settings]
[image: Turn off Auto login]

Answer (score 1):

I had to reset the SMC. It's really simple, depending on which mMac you have:

1. Unplug Mac from the power supply
2. Press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd> buttons all 4 together for at least 10 second then release
3. Startup again and it worked for me

Resetting the SMC clears a lot of problems but make sure you have your passwords for your email accounts as it resets them as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. All of the above were very helpful. I also found these two steps to be effective for me, albeit with minor setbacks. It's worth a double check if the above is still not working.

1.  menu > System Preferences > **Energy Saver**
2. Make sure the option **Wake For Network Access** is Unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

[Resetting my NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) (PRAM) seems to have solved this for me. Had this problem with macOS 12.6.6 and 12.6.7 on my Intel iMac.

Comment: There’s [nothing in NVRAM that’s related to passwords](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407319/119271).  It is much more likely that the inherent reboot solved your issue.

Comment: Possibly! Although I will note that I tried the other answers for this question first, and [the inherent reboot after resetting the SMC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/430346/376167) didn't fix it. I also rebooted as part of upgrading from 12.6.6 to 12.6.7 while troubleshooting this.

I wonder if NVRAM holds any power management-related values that might have an effect.