# Macbook (Big Sur) not asking for password after closing lid

Tags: crash, launchd, error, kernel-panic

**Problem**: This past month I noticed my MacBookPro does not lock the screen after closing the lid. This happened twice in the past month and occurred again today. The logs are filled with `google chrome` and `launchd` stuff when the lid was supposedly closed. In the morning after around 7 hours, I woke up to it unlocked and right where I left off.

**What I have done so far:** Fresh install of macOS and reset SMC and NVRAM.

**Question**: What can I do to solve this potential security issue?

```
Mar 1 11:11:15 macs-MBP Google Chrome Helper[8039]: Libnotify: notify_register_coalesced_registration failed with code 9 on line 2835
Mar 1 11:11:15 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 1 11:11:15 macs-MBP Google Chrome Helper[8038]: Libnotify: notify_register_coalesced_registration failed with code 9 on line 2835
Mar 1 11:11:15 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 1 11:11:15 macs-MBP Google Chrome Helper[8040]: Libnotify: notify_register_coalesced_registration failed with code 9 on line 2835
Mar 1 11:11:17 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Mar 1 11:11:17 macs-MBP com.apple.xpc.la
```

Comment: Mar 1 11:11:15 macs-MBP Google Chrome Helper[8039]: Libnotify: notify_register_coalesced_registration failed with code 9 on line 2835 Mar 1 11:11:15 --- last message repeated 1 time --- Mar 1 11:11:15 macs-MBP Google Chrome Helper[8038]: Libnotify: notify_register_coalesced_registration failed with code 9 on line 2835 Mar 1 11:11:15 --- last message repeated 1 time --- Mar 1 11:11:15 macs-MBP Google Chrome Helper[8040]: Libnotify: notify_register_coalesced_registration failed with code 9 on line 2835 Mar 1 11:11:17 --- last message repeated 4 times --- Mar 1 11:11:17 macs-MBP com.apple.xpc.la

Comment: Please edit you question to add log output, it's difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: Have you looked into settings under `security` and `general` to make sure your password is required after a short amount of time?

Comment: Yes, i have. it is set to require a password immediately after the macbook sleeps. I also have multiple tabs and windows of chrome, spss and word open as i am doing research for a thesis. could an issue with ram availability cause the mac to not sleep properly? i first time it happen when it was on battery, and the second on power.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, though in my case, this is due to the fact that these messages start appearing because the machine is slowly locking up. This can happen while asleep, which means that the password screen is never triggered when you wake from sleep.

It's a curious kind of freeze, though, because lots of functionality remains. Anything that might be relevant to solving the problem (iTerm, Force Quit) just beachballs when you attempt to access it.

This leads to at least 1-2 crashes per day (down from 1-2 crashes per hour when I first installed Big Sur).

Comment: Possibly relevant.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266420/macbook-not-asking-for-password-after-sleep
Have the same issue, SMC does not make any difference. After month of tests it happened several times.
Now tried method from the link.